# Как объединить таксономии в url?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url

Имеется две taxonomy на сайте: listing_city и listing_type. Внутри них присутствуют рубрики (города в первой, типы апартаментов в другой).
Логика url в таксономиях такова:

***listing_city = testsite/city/london***

***listing_type = testsite/type/apartment***

Как я могу реализовать страницу, которая объединяла бы эти две таксономии?

Например, получить страницу с URL ***testsite/city/london/apartment***.
Пробовал вот так, но это не сработало для меня.

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^listing/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$',
        'index.php?listing_city=$matches[1]&listing_type=$matches[2]',
        'top' );
```

Comment: Так тебе страницу с выдачей или урл? И что-то не вижу разницы в названиях таксономий

Comment: Извиняюсь, уже исправил!
Да, мне нужно объединить две этих таксономии. При добавлении объекта, мы указывает его тип апартаментов и город. 
Поэтому мне хотелось бы получать страницу, где например будут апартаменты только для конкретного города.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query изучай

Comment: А вообще ИМХО лучше города сделать отдельным типом контента, а типы недвиги - таксономией.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь!